# How do you set an environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables

Please explain how to set environment variables. I need to point an environment variable to a xml file.

Comment: Very ambiguous question. This might actually be related to the removed RHEL tag, in the case this was about changing values of default environment variables.

Comment: @Stephanie I made that edit to the question scope based on the accepted answer and the fact that there was no hint of defaults or boot time. Of not correct the OP needs to specify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the sh type of shell:

```
 YOURVARIABLE='/path/to/file'
 export YOURVARIABLE
```

In a csh type of shell:

```
 setenv YOURVARIABLE '/path/to/file'
```

Comment: Also in sh-derivatives you can do `export YOURVARIABLE=/path/to/file` as a single step, and don't forget that you can do `YOURVARIABLE=/path/to/file ./someCommand` to have the variable only affect that single command invocation.

Answer (score 1):

To set System-wide environment variables add name-value pair in /etc/environment file(YOUR_VARIABLE=/path/to/file).
Source: http://www.eguys.org/2012/04/system-wide-environment-variables.html

Comment: That's distribution-specific and generally not useful for the sort of thing the OP was asking about.